# iOs Swift Table View Problems

Tags: ios, swift

I have created an app which table can take multiple button button that can be scrolled in the row.
It is working but i have noticed when i scroll down that it mixes my values.
Lets say in the first row i have 3 button than in the 5-6 and sixth one i also have the last two information from the buttons added to it.I have no idea why is this happening.When in try to print the number of buttons,and positions of them it gives me a correct value but when i run it another sorry is happening.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return roundNumber

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell : RoundWorkoutCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! RoundWorkoutCell
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Cell", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! RoundWorkoutCell;
    }
    let exerviseName = RoundLabels[indexPath.row]

    if(indexPath.row == 0){

        for countMe in 0..<self.round_1_exercises.count {
            if(countMe<1){
                roundPosition1.append(5)
            }else{
                roundPosition1.append(115+roundPosition1[countMe-1])
            }
            scrollerSize = 115+roundPosition1[countMe]
        }

    }else if(indexPath.row == 1){
        for countMe in 0..<self.round_2_exercises.count {
            if(countMe<1){
                roundPosition2.append(5)
            }else{
                roundPosition2.append(115+roundPosition2[countMe-1])
            }
            scrollerSize = 115+roundPosition2[countMe]
        }
    }else if(indexPath.row == 2){
        for countMe in 0..<self.round_3_exercises.count {
            if(countMe<1){
                roundPosition3.append(5)
            }else{
                roundPosition3.append(115+roundPosition3[countMe-1])
            }
            scrollerSize = 115+roundPosition3[countMe]
        }
    }else if(indexPath.row == 3){
        for countMe in 0..<self.round_4_exercises.count {
            if(countMe<1){
                roundPosition4.append(5)
            }else{
                roundPosition4.append(115+roundPosition4[countMe-1])
            }
            scrollerSize = 115+roundPosition4[countMe]
        }
    }else if(indexPath.row == 4){
        for countMe in 0..<self.round_5_exercises.count {
            if(countMe<1){
                roundPosition5.append(5)
            }else{
                roundPosition5.append(115+roundPosition5[countMe-1])
            }
            scrollerSize = 115+roundPosition5[countMe]
        }
    }else if(indexPath.row == 5){
        for countMe in 0..<self.round_6_exercises.count {
            if(countMe<1){
                roundPosition6.append(5)
            }else{
                roundPosition6.append(115+roundPosition6[countMe-1])
            }
            scrollerSize = 115+roundPosition6[countMe]
        }
    }else if(indexPath.row == 6){
        for countMe in 0..<self.round_7_exercises.count {
            if(countMe<1){
                roundPosition7.append(5)
            }else{
                roundPosition7.append(115+roundPosition7[countMe-1])
            }
            scrollerSize = 115+roundPosition7[countMe]
        }
    }.....




    cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGFloat(scrollerSize),115)
    cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true
    cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.indicatorStyle = .Default


    if(indexPath.row==0){
        for index in 0..<self.round_1_exercises.count {
            print("Round position 1 \(self.roundPosition1[index])")

            var imageView : UIImageView
            imageView  = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x:roundPosition1[index],y: 5, width:110, height: 110 ))
            imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(imageView)

            let label1: UILabel = UILabel()
            label1.frame = CGRect(x:roundPosition1[index],y: 5, width:110, height: 20 )
            label1.textColor = UIColor(red:17/255.0, green: 22/255.0, blue: 40/255.0, alpha:1.0)
            label1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
            label1.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans-CondensedLight", size: 14)
            label1.text = exerciseInfo.exercise_name(self.round_1_exercises[index] as! String)
            cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(label1)

            let frame1 = CGRect(x:roundPosition1[index]+10,y:25, width:90, height: 90 )
            let button = UIButton(frame: frame1)
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: (self.round_1_exercises[index] as? String)!) as UIImage?, forState: .Normal)
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
            button.setTitle(self.round_1_exercises[index] as? String, forState: .Normal)
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor(red:0/255,green:0/255,blue:0/255,alpha:0.0), forState: .Normal)
            button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClick:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(button)

            let label: UILabel = UILabel()
            label.frame = CGRect(x:roundPosition1[index],y: 115, width:110, height: 20 )
            label.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 14)
            label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
            label.text = self.round_1_decoration[index] as? String
            cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(label)

        }

    }else if(indexPath.row == 1){
        for index in 0..<self.round_2_exercises.count {
             print("Round position 2 \(self.roundPosition2[index])")

            var imageView : UIImageView
            imageView  = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x:roundPosition2[index],y: 5, width:110, height: 110 ))
            imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(imageView)

            let label1: UILabel = UILabel()
            label1.frame = CGRect(x:roundPosition2[index],y: 5, width:110, height: 20 )
            label1.textColor = UIColor(red:17/255.0, green: 22/255.0, blue: 40/255.0, alpha:1.0)
            label1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
            label1.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans-CondensedLight", size: 14)
            label1.text = exerciseInfo.exercise_name(self.round_2_exercises[index] as! String)
            cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(label1)

            let frame1 = CGRect(x:roundPosition2[index]+10,y:25, width:90, height: 90 )
            let button = UIButton(frame: frame1)
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: (self.round_2_exercises[index] as? String)!) as UIImage?, forState: .Normal)
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
            button.setTitle(self.round_2_exercises[index] as? String, forState: .Normal)
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor(red:0/255,green:0/255,blue:0/255,alpha:0.0), forState: .Normal)
            button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClick:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(button)

            let label: UILabel = UILabel()
            label.frame = CGRect(x:roundPosition2[index],y: 115, width:110, height: 20 )
            label.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 14)
            label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
            label.text = self.round_2_decoration[index] as? String
            cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(label)

        }
    }else if(indexPath.row == 2){
        for index in 0..<self.round_3_exercises.count {
             print("Round position 3 \(self.roundPosition3[index])")

            var imageView : UIImageView
            imageView  = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x:roundPosition3[index],y: 5, width:110, height: 110 ))
            imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(imageView)

            let label1: UILabel = UILabel()
            label1.frame = CGRect(x:roundPosition3[index],y: 5, width:110, height: 20 )
            label1.textColor = UIColor(red:17/255.0, green: 22/255.0, blue: 40/255.0, alpha:1.0)
            label1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
            label1.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans-CondensedLight", size: 14)
            label1.text = exerciseInfo.exercise_name(self.round_3_exercises[index] as! String)
            cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(label1)

            let frame1 = CGRect(x:roundPosition3[index]+10,y:25, width:90, height: 90 )
            let button = UIButton(frame: frame1)
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: (self.round_3_exercises[index] as? String)!) as UIImage?, forState: .Normal)
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
            button.setTitle(self.round_3_exercises[index] as? String, forState: .Normal)
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor(red:0/255,green:0/255,blue:0/255,alpha:0.0), forState: .Normal)
            button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClick:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(button)

            let label: UILabel = UILabel()
            label.frame = CGRect(x:roundPosition3[index],y: 115, width:110, height: 20 )
            label.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 14)
            label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
            label.text = self.round_3_decoration[index] as? String
            cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(label)

        }
    }else if(indexPath.row == 3){
        for index in 0..<self.round_4_exercises.count {
             print("Round position 4 \(self.roundPosition4[index])")

            var imageView : UIImageView
            imageView  = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x:roundPosition4[index],y: 5, width:110, height: 110 ))
            imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(imageView)

            let label1: UILabel = UILabel()
            label1.frame = CGRect(x:roundPosition4[index],y: 5, width:110, height: 20 )
            label1.textColor = UIColor(red:17/255.0, green: 22/255.0, blue: 40/255.0, alpha:1.0)
            label1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
            label1.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans-CondensedLight", size: 14)
            label1.text = exerciseInfo.exercise_name(self.round_4_exercises[index] as! String)
            cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(label1)

            let frame1 = CGRect(x:roundPosition4[index]+10,y:25, width:90, height: 90 )
            let button = UIButton(frame: frame1)
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: (self.round_4_exercises[index] as? String)!) as UIImage?, forState: .Normal)
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
            button.setTitle(self.round_4_exercises[index] as? String, forState: .Normal)
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor(red:0/255,green:0/255,blue:0/255,alpha:0.0), forState: .Normal)
            button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClick:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(button)

            let label: UILabel = UILabel()
            label.frame = CGRect(x:roundPosition4[index],y: 115, width:110, height: 20 )
            label.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 14)
            label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
            label.text = self.round_4_decoration[index] as? String
            cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(label)

        }
    }else if(indexPath.row == 4){
        for index in 0..<self.round_5_exercises.count {
             print("Round position 5 \(self.roundPosition5[index])")

            var imageView : UIImageView
            imageView  = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x:roundPosition5[index],y: 5, width:110, height: 110 ))
            imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(imageView)

            let label1: UILabel = UILabel()
            label1.frame = CGRect(x:roundPosition5[index],y: 5, width:110, height: 20 )
            label1.textColor = UIColor(red:17/255.0, green: 22/255.0, blue: 40/255.0, alpha:1.0)
            label1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
            label1.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans-CondensedLight", size: 14)
            label1.text = exerciseInfo.exercise_name(self.round_5_exercises[index] as! String)
            cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(label1)

            let frame1 = CGRect(x:roundPosition5[index]+10,y:25, width:90, height: 90 )
            let button = UIButton(frame: frame1)
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: (self.round_5_exercises[index] as? String)!) as UIImage?, forState: .Normal)
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
            button.setTitle(self.round_5_exercises[index] as? String, forState: .Normal)
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor(red:0/255,green:0/255,blue:0/255,alpha:0.0), forState: .Normal)
            button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClick:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(button)

            let label: UILabel = UILabel()
            label.frame = CGRect(x:roundPosition5[index],y: 115, width:110, height: 20 )
            label.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 14)
            label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
            label.text = self.round_5_decoration[index] as? String
            cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(label)

        }
    }else if(indexPath.row == 5){
        for index in 0..<self.round_6_exercises.count {
             print("Round position 6 \(self.roundPosition6[index])")

            var imageView : UIImageView
            imageView  = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x:roundPosition6[index],y: 5, width:110, height: 110 ))
            imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(imageView)

            let label1: UILabel = UILabel()
            label1.frame = CGRect(x:roundPosition6[index],y: 5, width:110, height: 20 )
            label1.textColor = UIColor(red:17/255.0, green: 22/255.0, blue: 40/255.0, alpha:1.0)
            label1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
            label1.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans-CondensedLight", size: 14)
            label1.text = exerciseInfo.exercise_name(self.round_6_exercises[index] as! String)
            cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(label1)

            let frame1 = CGRect(x:roundPosition6[index]+10,y:25, width:90, height: 90 )
            let button = UIButton(frame: frame1)
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: (self.round_6_exercises[index] as? String)!) as UIImage?, forState: .Normal)
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
            button.setTitle(self.round_6_exercises[index] as? String, forState: .Normal)
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor(red:0/255,green:0/255,blue:0/255,alpha:0.0), forState: .Normal)
            button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClick:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(button)

            let label: UILabel = UILabel()
            label.frame = CGRect(x:roundPosition6[index],y: 115, width:110, height: 20 )
            label.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 14)
            label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
            label.text = self.round_6_decoration[index] as? String
            cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(label)

        }
    }....


    cell.RoundExercise_Cell_Label.text = exerviseName

    return cell as RoundWorkoutCell
}

func buttonClick(sender:AnyObject){
    exerciseName = sender.currentTitle
    //print(sender.currentTitle)
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showExercise", sender:exerciseName)
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This might be caused because of resue UITableView please check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33364419/swift-segmented-control-behaves-in-a-weird-way-in-uitableview-cell/33364832#33364832

Comment: I also think that it might be the problem,there is no other explanation for it.I was going throught the code step by step and it look good.I will try now to try the source you have me